# Selecting an ontology methodology for developing ontology

Tags: owl, semantic-web, ontology, methodology

My question is that is it mandatory to follow any ontology methodology while developing an ontology?

As per my understandings:

1. You can develop an ontology without following any specific methodology
2. You can strictly follow an ontology methodology according to your need/context of your ontology/project.
3. Instead of strictly following, you can partially/ loosely follow an ontology methodology according to your need/context of your ontology/project
4. You can even merge steps from multiple ontologies according to your need/context of your ontology/project.
5. One cannot say that one methodology (i.e NeOn Methodology) is better than another one. you can select any methodology according to your need.
6. Ontology Development Guidelines and Methodology are same things.

Please comment/guide me point by point. Thanks.

Comment: How *could* it be mandatory?

Comment: That’s not what I mean. I wonder what you mean with "mandatory". Who or what could mandate how you build your ontology?

Comment: @unor . Maybe Syed is saying "mandatory" in the sense that what you're making is no longer an ontology, but a pizza.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some examples of scientific papers about ontologies construction. These are not "mandatory" but good guidelines indeed.

> Kolas, D., Dean, M., & Hebeler, J. (2006). Geospatial Semantic Web:
>   Architecture of Ontologies (p. 1‑10). IEEE.
>   https://doi.org/10.1109/AERO.2006.1656068
>
> Denaux, R., Dolbear, C., Hart, G., Dimitrova, V., & Cohn, A. G.
>   (2011). Supporting domain experts to construct conceptual ontologies:
>   A holistic approach. Web Semantics: Science, Services and Agents on
>   the World Wide Web, 9, 113‑127.
>   https://doi.org/10.1016/j.websem.2011.02.001
>
> Tan, H., Adlemo, A., Tarasov, V., & Johansson, M. E. (2017).
>   Evaluation of an Application Ontology. In CEUR Workshop Proceedings
>   (Vol. 2050). Bolzano, Italy.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing mandatory about how to develop an ontology. However, people have found pitfalls and repeating patterns, hence some methodologies have been developed.

Which one is best for your objectives is very dependent on your objectives. There can be no absolute, general rule.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the user which method of ontology the user wants to implements. As long as theres no duplication and the data quality is maintained its good to produce and implement.

Answer (score 0):

As the general motivation for using ontologies is to eliminate differences in the meanings of terminologies among different stakeholders, its a good practice to follow some proven ontology development methodologies while developing the ontology to eliminate ontological inadequacies. One way to validate ontological adequacy of taxonomic relationships is by applying the [OntoClean](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nicola_Guarino/publication/285865694_An_overview_of_OntoClean_in_Handbook_on_Ontologies/links/56d0242c08ae85c82346f8f6.pdf) methodology, which was one of the first attempts to formalize notions of ontological analysis for information systems. It is based on the general ontological notions drawn from philosophy, like essence, identity, unity, rigidity, and dependence, used to characterize relevant aspects of the intended meaning of the properties, classes, and relations that make up an ontology, and imposing constraints on the taxonomic structure of an ontology.

A common mistake while developing ontologies is the 'misuse' of IS_A relation, commonly known as the IS_A overloading problem, which can be detected and prevented by applying the OntoClean method.

So yes, its a good practice to follow ontology validating methodologies such as OntoClean for validating the ontological adequacy of taxonomic relationships.